# Rssreader in codename

Tags: rss, codenameone, feed

I want to develop rssreader in codename so i use rssreader component in codename.
And I use the following url:
`feed://codenameone.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss`
which displays list of title and when I click on the list ,it shows the detial of the news. It is looking ok.

But my problem is when i use the following link of bbc:
`feed://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/video_and_audio/news_front_page/rss.xml?edition=uk`
it displays list and when i click it displays only description only , I want to display detail of  the news , How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to derive the `RSSReader` class and override the method `protected void showRSSEntry(Hashtable h)` where you can do pretty much anything you want to show the specific entry.

Comment: Thank dear Shai, 
I create new component OwnRssReader by extending RssReader and then override the showRssEntry method . 
still I have one problem , how can put this my component Ownrssreader in Codename one designer ,
so that I can drap and drop this component to make UI ?

Comment: You can't. In the before show event just add your customized component, in the designer remove the RSSReader you dragged into place.